# How to compare all list itetms in Python shortest

Tags: python

I want to be able to get True if all the list's items are the same:

For example checking this list would return True:

```
myList = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

While checking this list would result to False:

```
myList = [2,2,2,2,2,2,1]
```

What would be a shortest solution without a need to declare any new variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `set` would drop duplicates. Then you can chcek the `len`gth, to get the number of different values.

```
len(set(myList)) <= 1
```

This works if the values are hashable.

However, if you expect to run this on long lists and expect a negative answer often, short circuiting might prove faster:

```
def is_unique(myList):
   seen = set()
   for x in myList:
       seen.add(x)
       if len(seen) > 1:
          return False
   return True
```

Comment: Smart and simple! Thanks!

Comment: My two cents: I would use a `collections.counter`, just because it gives a little more information about the distribution of the elements in the list, while maintaining the same time and space complexity (while still under the "hashable items" assumption)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget `Collections.Counter` is implemented in Python, so it is no where near sets when it comes to speed.

Comment: @200OK: touché. I was thinking more of big-O complexity